# Create a simple system to students and subjects

Tags: java, oop

I started to study java and i'm try to do a simple system to associate students and subjects, my problem is how can i associate one student to many subjects, i hope you can help me.

Main Class

```
package exercicios;

public class Exercicio3_Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Criando Alunos
    Exercicio3_Aluno aluno[] = new Exercicio3_Aluno[3];
    aluno[0] = new Exercicio3_Aluno("Douglas", "Telematica", 201391);

    //Criando as Disciplinas
    Exercicio3_Disciplina disciplina[] = new Exercicio3_Disciplina[7];
    disciplina[0] = new Exercicio3_Disciplina("POO");

    aluno[0].cadastrarDisciplina(disciplina[0]);
    //aluno[0].listarAluno();
}
}
```

Student Class

```
package exercicios;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Exercicio3_Aluno {
public String nome;
public String curso;
private int matricula;
private ArrayList<Exercicio3_Disciplina> disciplina;

public Exercicio3_Aluno(String nome, String curso, int matricula) {
    super();
    this.nome = nome;
    this.curso = curso;
    this.matricula = matricula;
}

public void listarAluno(){
    System.out.println("------------- ALUNO --------------");
    System.out.println("Nome: " + this.getNome());
    System.out.println("Curso: " + this.getCurso());
    System.out.println("Matricula: " + this.getMatricula());
    System.out.println("Disciplinas: " + disciplina);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------");
}

//Metodos Acessores
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getCurso() {
    return curso;
}
public void setCurso(String curso) {
    this.curso = curso;
}
public int getMatricula() {
    return matricula;
}
public void setMatricula(int matricula) {
    this.matricula = matricula;
}

public void cadastrarDisciplina(Exercicio3_Disciplina disciplina){
    this.disciplina.add(disciplina);
}
}
```

Subjects Class

```
package exercicios;

public class Exercicio3_Disciplina {
public String nome;
private float nota1;
private float nota2;
private float nota3;
private float media;

public Exercicio3_Disciplina(String nome) {
    super();
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public float getNota1() {
    return nota1;
}

public void setNota1(float nota1) {
    this.nota1 = nota1;
}

public float getNota2() {
    return nota2;
}

public void setNota2(float nota2) {
    this.nota2 = nota2;
}

public float getNota3() {
    return nota3;
}

public void setNota3(float nota3) {
    this.nota3 = nota3;
}

public float getMedia() {
    return media;
}

public void setMedia(float media) {
    this.media = media;
}
}
```

The output of this code is something like this:

Nome: Douglas

Curso: TLM

Matrícula: 102050

Disciplinas: Programação Orientada a Objetos

What i need is list many subjects to students, i know it's probably is very simple but i started to study this now and all of this is new for me ;D

Comment: you might want to look into [Maps](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/map.html). Once you override `equals` and `hashCode`, you can do something like `Map<Student, List<Subject>> tempMap = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of one subject, you want multiple subjects on the student so use `List<Subjects>` on the student class and adjust the getters and setters as such. You can then add subjects to the list on the student.

Sample code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Criando os Alunos
    Exercicio3_Aluno aluno[] = new Exercicio3_Aluno[3];
    aluno[0] = new Exercicio3_Aluno("Douglas", "TLM", 102050);

    //Criando as Disciplinas
    Exercicio3_Disciplina disciplina[] = new Exercicio3_Disciplina[7];
    disciplina[0] = new Exercicio3_Disciplina("Programação Orientada a Objetos");
    disciplina[1] = new Exercicio3_Disciplina("Sistemas Operacionais");

    //Mostrando os dados do Aluno
    aluno[0].cadastrarDisciplina(disciplina[0]);
    aluno[0].cadastrarDisciplina(disciplina[1]);
    aluno[0].listaAluno();
}
```

In your student method

```
//Lista o Aluno
public void listaAluno(){
    System.out.println("--------- DADOS DO ALUNO --------");
    System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nome);
    System.out.println("Curso: " + this.curso);
    System.out.println("Matrícula: " + this.matricula);

    System.out.println("Disciplinas: ");
    String disciplinasString = "";
    for(Exercicio3_Disciplina disciplina : this.disciplinas)
    {
         disciplinasString = disciplinasString + disciplina.getNome());
    }
    System.out.println(disciplinasString);
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: I'm tried to do that, i try this:

    public class Exercicio3_Aluno {
 private ArrayList<Exercicio3_Disciplina> disciplina;}

the method to insert

    public void cadastrarDisciplina(Exercicio3_Disciplina disciplina){
  this.disciplina.add(disciplina);}

and the main code
  
  Exercicio3_Disciplina disciplina[] = new Exercicio3_Disciplina[7];
  disciplina[0] = new Exercicio3_Disciplina("POO");
  
  aluno[0].cadastrarDisciplina(disciplina[0]);
  aluno[0].listarAluno();

Comment: This looks a bit wrong, let me add what I think it should look like to the answer for you.

Comment: My comment was terrible, so i edit my code i think it's better to see. thanks

Comment: Hopefully this code works for you, I'm guessing the syntax and trying to stick to your language. Remember to name any list of things as a multiple so hopefully disciplinas for a list instead of disciplina. Let me know how it goes